# What is the difference between the two sentences?

Tags: difference, sentence-structure

1. The food gets cooked.
2. The food is cooked.

I get to hear both of the sentences. Are they same or different. Please explain, Sir.

Answer (score 2):

> The food gets cooked.

Cooking is what happens to the food.

For example:

> At the cafeteria, rice gets cooked in large vats.

Whereas with **is**:

> The food is cooked.

the meaning can be the same:

> At the cafeteria, rice is cooked in large vats.

or it can be different:

> This fish is cooked.

The fish is not raw. A cook prepared it in some way: frying, baking, broiling, steaming, smoking, etc.

Comment: Also, "is cooked" is in passive form, so "by (someone)" can be added after it.

Comment: **gets cooked** can also have a "by (someone)" phrase added.